# Laravel 4.1: URL ended with "/" not working

Tags: php, laravel-4

I just found that with Laravel 4.1, when an URL ended with "/" it will not works. For example: `mydomain.com/contactus` works, but `mydomain.com/contactus/` not working.

This usually wasn't a problem with Laravel 4.0. How can I fix this to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 4.1 `.htaccess` has a redirect rule to manage that, look at the `Redirect Trailing Slashes...`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I guess it is caused by my wampServer. Tried with xampp and newer wampserver on other pc, it works fine.